# Moving applications from the Internal Storage to my SD Card

Tags: applications, internal-storage, external-sd

How can I move applications from my internal storage on my Android 4.4.4 to my SD Card? I am trying to move Facebook to my SD Card so that I can update it.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image: The move to SD Card is disabled.]

I have tried:

- Rebooting the phone.
- Removing the SD Card.
- Unmounting the SD Card.

I don't have access to a Computer and Laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Uninstall updates" and "Disable" buttons in your screenshot show that this app is installed in the system image: that is, it was pre-installed on the phone, not installed by the user. System apps can't be moved to the SD card.

Comment: Then how can I update them? Google Play says that I can't update them because of their default location.

Comment: Since this is your real problem, please ask a question about this. Give full details including the text of any error messages and what phone you have.

Comment: This is the question: [Google Play won't allow me to update applications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197642/google-play-wont-allow-me-to-update-applications)

Answer (score 0):

i achieved that, with you diferent way, one was with the aplication ES File Explorer that allow you move files manually and it give to you more options that the configuration of the android, and the other way that i use was download a apk of the app i really dont know why with the apk app allow me to change the Location and with the official not.