# Google Play won't allow me to update applications

Tags: google-play-store, updates, default-applications

Google Play will not allow me to update my Facebook Application. It keeps saying that I can't update Facebook because of its default location.

[[image: Can't Install app <code>Error: -19</code>][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ7n0.png)]

My phone is an **Android 4.4.4, Gualcomm® snapdragon**

---

I have looked at the link that @SSS has directed me too, but it doesn't help. If I go to **Settings**->**Storage**, I don't see *Set SD Card as default*.

My phone's model number is *MTN-8978P* and it is an *Android 4.4.4*.

Comment: Does your phone have an SD card slot?

Comment: Yes. With an SD Card. 8GB. @SSS

Comment: What's the phone model? On googling the error I found [this](http://logixsnag.com/2016/05/fix-error-code-19-google-play-store/). Try if the solution works.

Comment: @SSS I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you try the following: remove SD card, restart phone, update app and reinsert card again. Remember to eject SD safely from storage settings.

Comment: @SSS. I tried it but it still didn't work. I got Error code: -20.  My Chrome is version 23.0.2.

Comment: Have you tried the following: clear data of play store, or remove google account from settings -> accounts and re-add it. If absolutely nothing works, go to https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/facebook/facebook-180-0-0-35-82-release/ and get the appropriate facebook version. Also are you sure you chrome is verwsion 23??? That's 5 years old maybe? You desperately need to update it.